# Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1) Flutter connecting mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, flutter, dart

I am getting this error in flutter when I am making my login page, I am sure that the server is returning JSON not HTML but I am still getting the error. I have even tried using some "test" links and I am getting the same error.

```
E/flutter (25538): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
E/flutter (25538): <br />
E/flutter (25538): ^
E/flutter (25538):
```

This is my code

```
  Future userLogin() async {
    setState(() {
      visible = true;
    });
    String email = emailController.text;
    String password = passwordController.text;
    var url = 'http://192.168.1.2/***************/*********.php';
    var data = {'email': email, 'password': password};
    var response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url), body: json.encode(data));
    var message = jsonDecode(response.body);
    if (message == 'Login Matched') {
      // Hiding the CircularProgressIndicator.
      setState(() {
        visible = false;
      });
      Navigator.push(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => StageOne()));
    } else {
      setState(() {
        visible = false;
      });
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: new Text(message),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                child: new Text("OK"),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: have you debugged the php code, also as your server doesn't use ssl, you can use wireshark , to view the communication directly, so u are sure what you receive, with out changing the code

Comment: Once you solve your server problem, the next issue will be `if (message == 'Login Matched')` `message` will be a map or a list, so won't match a string. Also, are you sure you server is expecting a JSON encoded (vs form encoded) body. Update the question showing a request in Postman that gets a valid response.